# tail recursion count, split & get the prefix of a list functions

Tags: string, list, scala, recursion

###### Language: Scala

I'm working on some *tail recursion* questions in *Scala*.

**(GOAL)** A function that counts the number of ones in a list. The function takes a list of ints and counts how many ones are in the list

*Restrictions include:*

- **No** loops (for-loops, while loops etc..), and **No** mutables (var).
- **Must** be tail recursive

What I have done:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

@tailrec
def countOnes(lst: List[Int], acc: Int = 0): Int = {
    
    if (lst.contains(1)){
        
         lst.count(_ == 1)
    }
    else {
        acc
    }
    countOnes(lst, acc)
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: In this `countOnes` the `if` and the recursion are unnecessary because you are _"cheating"_ and using `count` - Of course, in real code you would use `count` but this is a learning exercise and you were asked to use tail-recursion.

Comment: @TomKarzes All of these recursion functions do not seem to work for me when I test it on a simple input

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Right! That is part of both the question and the problem. It is a requirement for all of these functions to be Tail Recursive, regardless of that being the simple solution (which I have already come up with non-recursively)

Comment: You should ask exactly one question per question. In your question here, you have three questions and actually none of those three ask a question!

Answer (score 1):

One of the common approaches to solving such tasks is to use [pattern matching](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html). For example first one can look like:

```scala
@tailrec
def countOnes(lst: List[Int], acc: Int = 0): Int = lst match {
  case 1 :: tail => countOnes(tail, acc + 1) // if lists starts with one - increment acc and process the rest of it
  case _ :: tail => countOnes(tail, acc) // otherwise process the rest
  case Nil       => acc, // for empty list - return accumulator
}
```

The same approach can be applied to other 2.

Comment: Thank you! I see that pattern matching now. For the `sublist` function how would the helper function be incorporated? Would that also need case matches?

Comment: Also what does it mean when you did `case 1 :: tail =>`? Does this mean that when a 'one' is found that it adds it to the end of the list? or a new variable called tail? Can you do that same thing for a String data struc?

Comment: @VioletJohnson You're rushing too much! If you're learning using a course or something, just keep on to it, try to think about them and learn what tail recursion means (just for instance in your case), how it works, why is it used, when you understand the concept, you'll be able to implement every single of those. Same thing also applies for your question about pattern matching (`case 1 :: tail => `, etc. ). You'll get there soon, don't rush :)

Comment: @AminMal Thank you for the advice. I tend to do that. But yes, learning as with anything is a process. After looking over some more notes/examples I definitely think I understand it a bit better, but it still is rather confusing.